# How to add code ownership in Github directly through repository files

Tags: git, github, configuration

I am trying to add code ownership to my project files in repository.

***For example**: only specific group (`developers`) owns a specific component in project (`/app/important_feature`) and must be included as a pull request reviewer.*

I've read some articles and manually inserted file mapping in the `CODEOWNERS` text file.

***What is the best practice for managing code ownership in Github** repository?*

Comment: Do you really need to assign owners _per file_? `CODEOWNERS` work best with _file globs_, e.g. "everything in this directory", or "all files ending in `.java`.

Answer (score 2):

**Explanation**: In Github there's a great code ownership feature which can define individuals and teams that are responsible for code in repository.

**Examples**:

- Devops/SRE team must approve `.yml` configuration code changes in database of mysql and mongodb.
- backend team lead must review changes of a sensitive algorithm that related to a security component in some module in project.
- support engineer must verify code that related to special client's code.

From [docs](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/managing-your-repositorys-settings-and-features/customizing-your-repository/about-code-owners):

> People with admin or owner permissions can set up a CODEOWNERS file in
> a repository.
>
> The people you choose as code owners must have write permissions for
> the repository. When the code owner is a team, that team must be
> visible and it must have write permissions, even if all the individual
> members of the team already have write permissions directly, through
> organization membership, or through another team membership.
>
> Code owners are automatically requested for review when someone opens
> a pull request that modifies code that they own. Code owners are not
> automatically requested to review draft pull requests. For more
> information about draft pull requests, see "About pull requests." When
> you mark a draft pull request as ready for review, code owners are
> automatically notified. If you convert a pull request to a draft,
> people who are already subscribed to notifications are not
> automatically unsubscribed. For more information, see "Changing the
> stage of a pull request."
>
> When someone with admin or owner permissions has enabled required
> reviews, they also can optionally require approval from a code owner
> before the author can merge a pull request in the repository. For more
> information, see "About protected branches."
>
> If a team has enabled code review assignments, the individual
> approvals won't satisfy the requirement for code owner approval in a
> protected branch. For more information, see "Managing code review
> assignment for your team."

**Solution**: first create a `CODEOWNERS` in the root, docs/, or .github/ directory of the repository.

```
cd <your-project-path>
touch CODEOWNERS
```

Lets assume that:

- organization name is `CoolOrgName`
- R&D group contains 3 groups: `developers` / `backend` / `devops`

second, edit the `CODEOWNERS` file and set rules you want to apply in your project:

```
##########################################
#             code ownership
##########################################

# default ownership: default owners for everything in the repo (Unless a later match takes precedence)
*       @CoolOrgName/developers

# (Order is important, the last matching pattern takes the most precedence)
# When someone opens a pull request with .js files that only @backend team and not the global owner(s) will be requested for a review.
*.js    @CoolOrgName/backend

# only @devops team can review and approve this change related to .yml configuration
app/config/*.yml @CoolOrgName/devops

# only our CTO can review the change in our secret encrypted token
app/config/secret-token.txt @cto

# alternatively we can use email as well:
app/config/another-secret-token.txt cto@example.com

# any change inside the `/apps/sensetive-module/secured-component/` directory
# will require approval from "ninja" or "cto" users.
/apps/sensetive-module/secured-component/ @ninja @cto
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be one file per repo
https://help.github.com/articles/about-codeowners/